# Changing JS window object name happens automatically

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

```
console.log(`obj: ${this} name: ${this.name}`);


var myObj = {
  name: "",
  yell: function() {
    this.name = "Star Powerup"; 
    var changeName = function(newName) {
      this.name = newName;
    };
    changeName("Blue Shell");
    console.log(this);
  }
};
myObj.yell();
```

when messing around with JavaScript scope I found that when window was console logged at the beginning of the script its name was changed before the code that changes it gets executed. I know objects don't get hoisted, but even if that was the case, the invocation of the function would not be. I'm hoping someone know why this is.

Comment: So you understand that `changeName("Blue Shell")` changes the `window.name` because of how the `this` keyword works in sloppy mode? And you're just confused why the `console.log` in the first line already logs "Blue Shell" as the window name while it hasn't been changed yet?

Comment: yes that's what I would like to figure out. sorry if the question was misleading

Comment: Just checking so I can go search for the proper canonical question :-) To spoil the solution: [`window.name` is a special global property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) that names your tab (browser window) and persists across reloads. So if you execute this script twice, first time you'll get an empty string, second time it will remember the value you assigned the first time.

Comment: so essentially its just the browser assuming what window.name is then?

Comment: No assumption being made. `window.name` actually *has* the value `"Blue Shell"` in the first line, probably from one of your previous attempts of debugging the script. Go close your browser and reopen it, or open your page in a new tab: the first time this snippet runs, it actually logs the empty string as expected.

Comment: awesome, thank you that answers my question perfectly